# None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied error on Text Composable

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I can't understand why I keep getting this error on the TextComposable

```
Column(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(buttonSpacing)
        ) {

            Text(
                text = state.number1 + (state.operation?: "") + state.number2,
                textAlign = Alignment.End,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(vertical = 32.dp),
                fontSize = 32.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
                color = Color.White,
                maxLines = 2
                )

        }
```

Someone suggested I import this dependency: implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:$material3_version"
but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Wait I solved it smh

I typed `textAlign = Alignment.End` instead of

> textAlign = TextAlign.End